Trying to gain general understanding of PyCharm and file locations on Windows 11
I recently added PyCharm to my Windows 11 machine.
I have dabbled in Python before, and have installed 3.12
Now, I am creating a proof of concept Python script to talk to a bot on my Discord test server. I need to download the Discord library. I have tried downloading it using the pip command from the standard Win 11 command prompt that is independent of PyCharm, and also from both the Console and Terminal inside PyCharm.
The venv that PyCharm has set up for my project does not recognize nor see that Discord library. The
import discord
line of text gives me the error of
"no module named discord"
It is not case sensitive. I really do not understand exactly what a venv is in PyCharm, and where the files for this library (and I am sure there will need to be other libraries in the future) need to reside inside the Win 11 file structure for this PyCharm project to recognize them.

You'll have to install the discord library into the virtual environment - a virtual environment is a separate Python environment that doesn't get affected by other environments - it's just for your project. This is useful to avoid conflicts between different projects and suddenly having one project change the installed libraries for other projects. If you go to "terminal" in your PyCharm window, you can run pip install .. directly in your virtual environment (which will be activate in the terminal window). You can also use the "Python packages" tab in PyCharm to install into your venv.

Thank you. I believe my pip install command was badly formatted. I followed the instructions you gave, and ran "python -m pip install discord" from the terminal, rebooted PyCharm, and it now sees the discord library, although it is highlighted in red.
